# Ignore specific property when running a Spring Boot test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-properties

My Spring Boot application contains the following property in `src/main/resources/application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
 security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${AUTH_SERVER_METADATA_URL:http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo}
```

When running tests, e.g. `@WebMvcTest`, I don't have a running authorization server. Thus, I need to use the following configuration which I put into `src/test/resources/application-test.yml` and activate it by using the `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation.

```yaml
spring:
 security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          public-key-location: classpath:public_rsa.key
```

The problem is, that the application context loads both of the application property files which leads to a refused connection during the tests. Is it possible to selectively ignore the `issuer-uri` property during tests?

Comment: You can overwrite issuer-uri:  in your -test yaml property file.

Answer (score 1):

If you rename src/test/resources/application-test.yml to src/test/resources/application.yml, it should override the file src/main/resources/application.yml